# PyTorch loading pretrained weights

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to load a pretrained model `resnet_18.pth` file into pytorch. Online documentation suggested importing like so:

```py
weights = torch.load("resnet_18.pth")
```

When I print the output of `weights`, it gives something like the following:

```
 ('module.layer4.1.bn2.running_mean', tensor([ 9.1797e+01, -2.4204e+02,  5.6480e+01, -2.0762e+02,  4.5270e+01,
        -3.2356e+02,  1.8662e+02, -1.4498e+02, -2.3701e+02,  3.2354e+01,
...
```

All of the tutorials mentioned loading weights using a base model:

```
model = TheModelClass(*args, **kwargs)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(PATH))
model.eval()
```

I want to use a default resnet-18 model to apply the weights on, but I the `resent18` from `tensorflow vision` does not have the `load_state_dict` function. Help is appreciated.

```py
from torchvision.models import resnet18
resnet18.load_state_dict(torch.load("resnet_18.pth"))

# 'function' object has no attribute 'load_state_dict'
```

Answer (score 0):

`resnet18` is itself a function that returns a `ResNet18` model. What you can do to load your own pretrained weights is to use

```
model = resnet18()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("resnet_18.pth"))
```

Note that `load_state_dict(...)` loads the weights in-place and does not return model itself.